# Filtering through arrays and strings at the same time?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, filtering

Here I am filtering through items:

```
let filter = this.props.data.filter(
  (item) => {
    return (
      item.fname.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.search.toLowerCase()) !== -1 ||
      item.lname.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.search.toLowerCase()) !== -1
    );
  }
);
```

So I am updating my table, whenever the user types something into the input field. However, there is not only `fname` and `lname`, there is also an array field called `[children]` which contains the names of the children the person has:

`children : ["Bob", "Andrew", "Mary-Jane"]`

I want to also filter if any of *those* names is typed in. How would I do this? I am a javascript / React beginner, so I would appreciate any help!

Comment: I think `array.includes(String)` would do the job.
[Array.prototype.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check if any element in the array has your search term as a substring:

```
const search = this.state.search.toLowerCase();
let filter = this.props.data.filter(
  (item) => {
    return (
      item.fname.toLowerCase().includes(search) ||
      item.lname.toLowerCase().includes(search) ||
      item.children.some(child => 
        child.toLowerCase().includes(search)
      )
    );
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a competely dynamic approach and take only an array of the wanted properties for iterating. If found take a short circuit to exit.

```
const search = this.state.search.toLowerCase();
let filter = this.props.data.filter(item => ['fname', 'lname', 'children'].some(k =>
        Array.isArray(item[k])
            ? item[k].some(v => v.toLowerCase().includes(search))
            : item[k].toLowerCase().includes(search)
    ));
```